# Using libraries built for linux on windows

Tags: windows, linux, gcc, porting

Is there a way of using libraries built in Linux on Windows, without porting and rebuilding them?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "No". Although there is a way of doing that vice-versa (via WINE).

Answer (score 1):

That would require loading [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) binaries. Extending the loader in Windows seems to be difficult if not impossible, going by the answers to this question:

[Is it possible to replace Loader of an OS? Any way to obtain the control over Loader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160433/is-it-possible-to-replace-loader-of-an-os-any-way-to-obtain-the-control-over-loa)